# How does nesting f# functions differ from not nesting them when nesting is optional?

Tags: f#, inline

I understand the benefit of nesting functions when you want to return a closure. But when a function is never used outside of the function it is defined in, is there a cost to keeping it nested?

Consider:

```
let private validate number = 
    number > 100

let validateAndPrint (i : int) = 
    printfn "%i Greater than 100: %s" i ((validate i).ToString())
```

Versus:

```
let validateAndPrint (i : int) = 
    let validate number = 
        number > 100
    printfn "%i Greater than 100: %s" i ((validate i).ToString())
```

The concern here is usually when I have a few of these inner functions and I only need to call one of them based on an execution path (it's usually not  prohibitive to keep these functions private or nested and test the permutations).

`validateAndPrint` could also be rewritten more tdd-friendly to take in the validate function:

```
let validateAndPrint validate i = ...
```

..but if `validation`'s signature contains an internal or private type then there is the consideration of making everything public and your parameter list blowing up.

Any crucial differences?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant

Comment: @MarkSeemann I've updated the title of the question. Really, I'm just interested in any and all differences (if the compiler interprets the two differently, or maybe if the fact that the code can be written both ways is a smell, etc...)

Comment: Sorry, I must have misinterpreted the original question!

Comment: @MarkSeemann no problem--agonizing over micro-optimizations usually deserves a good smacking with the book

Answer (score 7):

In `Release` mode, IL is identical and both versions of `validate` are inlined in this particular example.

You cannot rely on inlining always, e.g. if a function is "big" then compiler could choose not to inline it (this is true for methods, I am not 100% sure this is true for F# nested functions. It is not possible to mark them `inline` and force inlining, - need to consult F# specs if such functions behave like methods or are always inlined in Release). In the nested case in Debug mode, there is additional FSharpFunc allocation and `callvirt`. Without nesting it is just a static call without allocations, which is the cheapest of all possible implementations.

So in general, if nesting is truly optional it is safer to avoid it, because even if a function is not inlined it is always called as a static method. However, it matters only when you call this code several millions times per second.

**Not nested, static call on IL_0019:**

```
.method public static 
    void validateAndPrint (
        int32 i
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2104
    // Code size 51 (0x33)
    .maxstack 5
    .locals init (
        [0] class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>,
        [1] bool
    )

    IL_0000: ldstr "%i Greater than 100: %s"
    IL_0005: newobj instance void class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`5<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>, class [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, class [mscorlib]System.Tuple`2<int32, string>>::.ctor(string)
    IL_000a: call !!0 [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.ExtraTopLevelOperators::PrintFormatLine<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>>(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`4<!!0, class [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>)
    IL_000f: stloc.0
    IL_0010: nop
    IL_0011: ldloc.0
    IL_0012: newobj instance void FSSO.Test/validateAndPrint@8::.ctor(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>)
    IL_0017: ldarg.0
    IL_0018: ldarg.0
    IL_0019: call bool FSSO.Test::validate(int32)
    IL_001e: stloc.1
    IL_001f: ldloca.s 1
    IL_0021: constrained. [mscorlib]System.Boolean
    IL_0027: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
    IL_002c: call !!0 class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, string>::InvokeFast<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!0, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!1, !!0>>, !0, !1)
    IL_0031: pop
    IL_0032: ret
} // end of method Test::validateAndPrint
```

**Nested, allocation on IL_0018 and callvirt on IL_0020:**

```
.method public static 
    void validateAndPrint (
        int32 i
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 58 (0x3a)
    .maxstack 6
    .locals init (
        [0] class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, bool> validate,
        [1] class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>,
        [2] bool
    )

    IL_0000: newobj instance void FSSO.Test2/validate@13::.ctor()
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    IL_0006: ldstr "%i Greater than 100: %s"
    IL_000b: newobj instance void class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`5<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>, class [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, class [mscorlib]System.Tuple`2<int32, string>>::.ctor(string)
    IL_0010: call !!0 [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.ExtraTopLevelOperators::PrintFormatLine<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>>(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`4<!!0, class [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>)
    IL_0015: stloc.1
    IL_0016: nop
    IL_0017: ldloc.1
    IL_0018: newobj instance void FSSO.Test2/'validateAndPrint@14-2'::.ctor(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>)
    IL_001d: ldarg.0
    IL_001e: ldloc.0
    IL_001f: ldarg.0
    IL_0020: callvirt instance !1 class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, bool>::Invoke(!0)
    IL_0025: stloc.2
    IL_0026: ldloca.s 2
    IL_0028: constrained. [mscorlib]System.Boolean
    IL_002e: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
    IL_0033: call !!0 class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, string>::InvokeFast<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!0, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!1, !!0>>, !0, !1)
    IL_0038: pop
    IL_0039: ret
} // end of method Test2::validateAndPrint
```

**Release mode, inlined comparison on IL_0020:**

```
.method public static 
    void validateAndPrint (
        int32 i
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 57 (0x39)
    .maxstack 6
    .locals init (
        [0] class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>,
        [1] class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`4<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>, class [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>,
        [2] bool
    )

    IL_0000: ldstr "%i Greater than 100: %s"
    IL_0005: newobj instance void class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`5<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>, class [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, class [mscorlib]System.Tuple`2<int32, string>>::.ctor(string)
    IL_000a: stloc.1
    IL_000b: call class [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter [mscorlib]System.Console::get_Out()
    IL_0010: ldloc.1
    IL_0011: call !!0 [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule::PrintFormatLineToTextWriter<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>>(class [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`4<!!0, class [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>)
    IL_0016: stloc.0
    IL_0017: nop
    IL_0018: ldloc.0
    IL_0019: newobj instance void FSSO.Test2/'validateAndPrint@14-2'::.ctor(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>)
    IL_001e: ldarg.0
    IL_001f: ldarg.0
    IL_0020: ldc.i4.s 100
    IL_0022: cgt
    IL_0024: stloc.2
    IL_0025: ldloca.s 2
    IL_0027: constrained. [mscorlib]System.Boolean
    IL_002d: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
    IL_0032: call !!0 class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, string>::InvokeFast<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!0, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!1, !!0>>, !0, !1)
    IL_0037: pop
    IL_0038: ret
} // end of method Test2::validateAndPrint
```

Comment: I had a feeling there was a slight difference. And generally when I'm writing something that performs slower, I'm writing code that suffers from other design problems. So maybe a function that has several nested functions that doesn't take advantage of closures is a good code smell heuristic.

Comment: @moarboilerplate most often it is much easier to start with more readable code and get correctness first. And then it is not too hard to eliminate subtle issues such as `callvirt` and `Func` allocations when you see them on hot paths. Even the built-in profiler in VS2015 Community is good enough to find such issues.

Comment: Well in this case they are both readable. The performance isn't the issue since it's negligible, but perhaps the miniscule difference in performance is a sign of a larger design issue.

Comment: Such minor issues accumulate and create GC pressure and cache trashing at the scale of an entire program. .NET GC is knows to be very good for allocating short-lived small objects, but zero pressure is still better than very small pressure. In F#, there are non-obvious allocations like tuple expansion of `Try...` pattern with `byref`s, implicit ref cells, closures, which make programming easier and in most cases such small performance impact doesn't matter.

Comment: @V.B. FYI tuple allocation in Try patterns with byref params is now optimized away. https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/335

Comment: @Asik good to know! Recently I have cleaned all such cases manually in my code, and it tuned out that it was not needed!